# SQL Trigger "AFTER INSERT ON" not only not working, but stops main insert

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

[image]i am woriking on MySql database hosted by 000webhost using PhpMyAdmin.
My DB for now is very simple. I have 2 tables `accounts` and `lvl_time` that are connected by relation (`accounts`)`id`->`user_id`(`lvl_times`). I need to create row in `lvl_times` every time i create new field in `accounts`. New field in `lvl_times` needst to be have `user_id` same as newly created account.

I tried to use coupe of versions od "AFTER INSERT ON" triggers. Not only it's not working, but also triggers stops main insert and new accounts are somehow delated after insert.
For exaple i tried this trigger:

```
   CREATE TRIGGER createEmptylvlfields 
         AFTER INSERT ON accounts 
         FOR EACH ROW 
            INSERT INTO lvl_times (user_id) SELECT id FROM inserted
```

i attached the scheme of my simple db as image

Please help

Comment: This doesn't look like MySQL code to me.

Comment: Yeah, sorry i got despred and probably used also some solution form another post which was in SQLServer.

Answer (score 3):

Your trigger should be:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER createEmptylvlfields 
     AFTER INSERT ON accounts 
     FOR EACH ROW 
        INSERT INTO lvl_times (user_id) 
          VALUES (NEW.id);
```

And yes, if trigger fails the insert is rolled back.

Comment: i get #1064 syntax error on your trigger :/
"near 'NEW.id)' at line 5"

Comment: ok i changed you solution to
INSERT INTO lvl_times SET user_id =NEW.id

and it worked, thanks

Comment: Sorry my little mistake. I forget about the VALUES word. Let me fix it.